# Getting an error when printing the middle character of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

When trying to print the middle character of a string using the following code:

```
def mid(a):
    return a[(len(a) + 1) / 2]
    
print(mid("abc"))
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Changing it to:

```
 def mid(a):
    return a[(len(a) - 1) // 2 : (len(a) + 2) // 2]
    
print(mid("abc"))
```

outputs:

```
b
```

Why does directly grabbing the middle value return the TypeError, but grabbing the 0th value and then the middle value actually work?

Comment: Hint: What's the difference between `//` and `/` in Python 3?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz thanks! I had not realized that by doing a / 2 division the 2.0 i was getting was still a float, thanks for pointing out the subtle difference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division returns a float. You want floor division.

```
>>> 4/2
2.0
>>> 4//2
2
```

It seems like you fixed this without noticing in your changed code.